# flutter permission Handler grant not showing on iOS

Tags: flutter, dart

i created a class to ask for permission immediately it get to login, it show on Android but on iOs i am not seeing any permission grant.

```
class PermissionService {
  Future permissionHandler() async {
    await Permission.contacts.shouldShowRequestRationale;
    if (await Permission.contacts.request().isGranted) {
      // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
    }
    Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
      Permission.locationWhenInUse,
      Permission.locationAlways,
      Permission.photos,
      Permission.camera,
      Permission.location,
      Permission.microphone,
      Permission.notification,
    ].request();

    if (statuses[Permission.location].isDenied) {
      print("Location permission is denied.");
    }

    if (statuses[Permission.camera].isDenied) {
      print("Camera permission is denied.");
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.photos].isDenied) {
      print("Photos permission is denied.");
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.notification].isDenied) {
      print("Notification permission is denied.");
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.microphone].isDenied) {
      print("Microphone permission is denied.");
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.locationWhenInUse].isDenied) {
      print("locationWhenInUse permission is denied.");
    }
    if (statuses[Permission.locationAlways].isDenied) {
      print("locationAlways permission is denied.");
    }
  }
}
```

and i call this function in the initstate of the Login.dart

Comment: What is the version of `Permission` package and the iOS that does not show permission request?

Comment: permission_handler: ^8.1.4+2 and iOS 14.4

Comment: What do you have as `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` in you Podfile?

Comment: i cant find GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS this in my podfile

Comment: `permission_handler: ^10.4.5` package not asking to grant or decline the permissions in the popup.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The **permission_handler** package introduced a breaking change in version `8.0.0`, see [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler/changelog). Permissions on iOS are disabled by default, and you have the set the correct `GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS` in you Podfile. An example Podfile can be found [here](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/example/ios/Podfile), but basically you have to add this to you Podfile, set the permissions that you don't use to `0`:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # You can remove unused permissions here
      # for more infomation: https://github.com/BaseflowIT/flutter-permission-handler/blob/master/permission_handler/ios/Classes/PermissionHandlerEnums.h
      # e.g. when you don't need camera permission, just add 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=0'
      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= [
        '$(inherited)',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.calendar
        'PERMISSION_EVENTS=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.reminders
        'PERMISSION_REMINDERS=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.contacts
        'PERMISSION_CONTACTS=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
        'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.microphone
        'PERMISSION_MICROPHONE=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.speech
        'PERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.photos
        'PERMISSION_PHOTOS=1',
        ## dart: [PermissionGroup.location, PermissionGroup.locationAlways, PermissionGroup.locationWhenInUse]
        'PERMISSION_LOCATION=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.notification
        'PERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.mediaLibrary
        'PERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.sensors
        'PERMISSION_SENSORS=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.bluetooth
        'PERMISSION_BLUETOOTH=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.appTrackingTransparency
        'PERMISSION_APP_TRACKING_TRANSPARENCY=1',
        ## dart: PermissionGroup.criticalAlerts
        'PERMISSION_CRITICAL_ALERTS=1',
      ]
    end
  end
end
```

Edit 1: Once that is done, save your Podfile and then stop the current instance of the project since hot restart will not reflect the changes. Rebuild the project and `permission_handler` requests should now be working perfectly.

Edit 2: As suggested by @YugankaSharan it might be necessary to run `pod install` for the changes to take effect.

Comment: you might have to rebuild your app, I am not sure whether these changes require it or not

Comment: okay.. i will surely give u feedback on it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. Seems like Gbenga above did not give feedback. I tried the above method and it does work. You have to rebuild the app though and I have requested an edit to the answer with that as the last instruction.

Comment: @KennethMurerwa after i accept it, i thought there is no need for the feedback in comment

Comment: I also had to run pod install before the changes took effect.

Comment: @YugankaSharan Thank you, I will add this to the answer.

Comment: Can confirm this works. I removed unnecessary permissions and also added the necessary key/value pairs to my info.plist file. Performed `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get` and also `pod instal`. Only after requesting the permission and granting did the option to enable disable appear in my app's settings

Comment: @PeterKoltai, How to add it in podspecs? if I don't want to add in pod file in case of an SDK?

Comment: @Shoaib Unfortunately I don't know, I know only this Podfile based method.

Comment: good. works without 'pod install'

Comment: Still didn't work for me on physical iPhone device after deleting podfile.lock, clean, rebuild. I deleted app and restarted iPhone then it worked.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I also use this library. But the problem is not with the library. The app doesn't even show a dialog asking for location permissions. Then I go to settings, go to the app, and I don't see the requested location permission interface.

[image]

The problem was with my `Info.plist` file.

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> 
<string>Cho phép Chat truy cập thông tin vị trí để chia sẻ vị trí trong cuộc trò chuyện</string> 
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key> 
<string>Cho phép Chat truy cập thông tin vị trí để chia sẻ vị trí trong cuộc trò chuyện</string>
```

Permission `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` above `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` is wrong. Therefore, the order should be reversed.

Comment: I have the same issue, but with calendar permission.  During testing I had denied access, then uninstall and reinstalled the app, but now permission gets a permanently denied status and somehow that doesn't make an entry in Settings

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, in some packages (for example Alarm package), you may need to turn on some features from the Signing and Capabilities section. Keep in mind

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).