# give permission to read and use photos

Tags: firebase, flutter, permissions, imagepicker

I want to give my users the opportunity to upload a profile picture. Therefor I wrote some code with permissionHandler and image_picker packages.

```
MaterialButton(
          child: Text('Profilbild auswählen'),
          onPressed: () async {
            var status = await Permission.photos.status;
            print(status);
            if (status.isGranted) {
              final pickedFile =
                  await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
              print(pickedFile);
              setState(() {
                if (pickedFile != null) {
                  _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
                } else {
                  print('No image selected.');
                }
              });
            } else {
              showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Bilder Zugriff'),
                          content: Text(
                              'Wir brauchen zugriff auf deine Bilder um ein Profilbild hochladen zu können!'),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            CupertinoDialogAction(
                                child: Text('Grant'),
                                onPressed: () async {
                                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  await Permission.photos.request();
                                }),
                            CupertinoDialogAction(
                              child: Text('Settings'),
                              onPressed: () => openAppSettings(),
                            ),
                          ]));
            }
          }),
```

But the permission stays at status 'denied' although the iPhone-Settings allows the usage of gallery. How can I change that status in the application and does the rest of the code makes sense to upload the image to firebase? How is it possible to change the image live on the screen? Thought it works with .setState()...

Comment: Which version of permission handler package do you use?

Comment: Version 8.1.6, it should be the newest one.

Comment: Please check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599765/flutter-permission-handler-grant-not-showing-on-ios/68600411#68600411) and confirm if you have setup your Podfile.

Comment: Yeah, already added the code to the Podfile, deleted the application and restarted the debugging on iOS Simulator.

Comment: You request permission to `Permission.camera`, but check status of `Permission.photos`.

Comment: Oh, missed that. After selecting an image I want to update the screen/image with the setState method, is that correct? Because the image stays the same. thanks!

Comment: If it is a stateful widget then yes, you need to call setState to rebuild