# How to check permission in Flutter

Tags: flutter, permissions

I am using [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) and [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler). My app gets permission through [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker). However, when I check the status of the [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler), it still shows that the permission is denied. Please help.

```
Future<void> _pickImage() async{
var status1 = await Permission.photos.status;
var status2 = await Permission.mediaLibrary.status;
var status3 = await Permission.camera.status;
var status4 = await Permission.accessMediaLocation.status;
var status5 = await Permission.storage.status;
var status6 = await Permission.photosAddOnly.status;
print(status1);
print(status2);
print(status3);
print(status4);
print(status5);
print(status6);

if (status1.isDenied) {
  
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
    content: const Text(
      'permission_denied_message',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white
      ),
    ).tr(),
    action: SnackBarAction(
      label: tr('setting'),
      textColor: Colors.yellow[600],
      onPressed: (){
        openAppSettings();
      },
    ),
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    duration: const Duration(seconds: 5),
  ));
}
final pickedImage = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
imageFile = pickedImage != null ? File(pickedImage.path) : null;

_cropImage();
```

}

Comment: Have you added the permissions in androidManifest.xml

Comment: I'm testing on ios. I added the key to info.plist. A dialog asking for permission also appear, and if approved, it will also work well to import images from the gallery. However, when I check the status by permission_handler, it says that it has been rejected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599765/flutter-permission-handler-grant-not-showing-on-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your "gradle.properties" file:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Make sure you set the compileSdkVersion in your "android/app/build.gradle" file to 31:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 31
  ...
}
```

Make sure you replace all the android. dependencies to their AndroidX counterparts.
Add permissions to your **AndroidManifest.xml** file. There's a debug, main and profile versions which are chosen depending on how you start your app. In general, it's sufficient to add permission only to the main version.

Comment: I'm testing on ios. I added the key to info.plist. A dialog asking for permission also appear, and if approved, it will also work well to import images from the gallery. However, when I check the status by permission_handler, it says that it has been rejected.

Comment: open your podfile and check  
## dart: PermissionGroup.camera
# 'PERMISSION_CAMERA=1'
remove the '#' so that camera will get permission